# history push state change back to original url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page use **jquery load img into page (pop Box)** & i have use `history push state` change url

when user open the image, its a pop box, and i have set next image button inside of this box. something like facebook, so if user click next image, url will change again,

my problem is when user click close, how can I change back to original url.

```
window.history.back();
```

if i use history back, it only go back one page, what if user click next image few times?

Comment: do you want to use html5 pushState like facebook?

Comment: what is html5 push state?

Comment: html5 browser history manipulation, you can control the location par url without navigation away from your page.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: this is what i am using now, what im asking is because user may click next image button few time, and url text will keep changing, so when user close image box, i need to go back to original url

Comment: no you can use pushstate not back nor forward actions, this will not move you away from your current page.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState().C2.A0method